# Why do these 2 congruences imply the following?

Tags: congruences, congruence-relations

Suppose the following 2 congruences hold
\begin{equation*}
(x + \alpha)^n \equiv x^n + \alpha \hspace{4mm} (\text{mod} \hspace{2mm} x^r - 1, \hspace{2mm} p) \\
(x + \alpha)^p \equiv x^p + \alpha \hspace{4mm} (\text{mod} \hspace{2mm} x^r - 1, \hspace{2mm} p)
\end{equation*}

I am told that this implies the congruence
$$
(x + \alpha)^\frac{n}{p} \equiv x^\frac{n}{p} + \alpha \hspace{4mm} (\text{mod} \hspace{2mm} x^r - 1, \hspace{2mm} p)
$$

Can any one please explain to me why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean $\mod {(x^r-1,p)}$? I assume this.

The only possibilities for $(x^r-1,p)$ are $1$ and $p$.

►$(x^r-1,p)=p$

Because of the well known property  $(x+y)^p\equiv x+y\pmod p$ we have

$$(x+a)^{\frac np}\equiv x^{\frac np}+a\pmod p\iff(x+a)^n\equiv(x^{\frac np}+a)^p\equiv x^n+a$$ Therefore  only the first condition implies the condition to be proven.

►$(x^r-1,p)=1$

This case is trivial in the sense that all pair of integers are equivalent modulo $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I am still unsure as to why that property implies the $\iff$ statement?

Comment: In particular, I am unsure of where the $(x^{\frac np}+a)^p$ term came from?

Comment: Raised to the p-th power both members of the first equation.

Comment: Thanks, I have marked this as my accepted answer. On one final note, do you know where I might find a reference for the stated property?

Comment: I am terribly sorry, but I am still struggling to understand this. May I refer you to this question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2687739/given-xan-equivx-frac-npap-equiv-xna-prove-that-xa-frac-np?noredirect=1#comment5553514_2687739)?